# GWCode Categories and 2.11.1?

Tags: gwcode-categories

On one of our new builds, we're getting an "This site can't be reached" error when using GWCode Categories with EE 2.11.1.

Any reason for this? Haven't seen it with any other EE version. Here's the error message:

Severity: 8192
Message: Non-static method Gwcode_categories::usage() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
Filename: gwcode_categories/pi.gwcode_categories.php
Line Number: 29

Usually, this error can be resolved by changing the function usage() to public static usage(). However, in this instance the fix doesn’t seem to make a difference.

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Wild guess, looking at the plugin V1.8.9 line 29. The reference is all lowercase: gwcode_categories::usage(). Yet the class begins with an uppercase 'G'. This is the only module where I see this behavior (capitalisation).

Comment: Thanks stuartmcd69. I tried that but didn't resolve the issue. We've been using GWCC for years and this is the first time I'm having trouble like this.